# CoreData: "Cannot delete object that was never inserted."

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

For the life of me I can't work this one out, but CoreData keeps throwing me an error.

> Cannot delete object that was never inserted.

Here is the jist of my app cycle:

1/ Push ViewController.

2/ Get managed object context from app delegate.

```
FLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

3/ Check if `Session` exists.

4/ No `Session` exists, create a new one.

```
    self.session = nil;
            self.session = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    //Set attributes etc...

//Keep a reference to this session for later
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setURL:self.session.objectID.URIRepresentation forKey:kKeyStoredSessionObjectIdUriRep];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
            {
                //Handle error if save fails
            }
```

5/ Pop ViewController.

6/ Return to ViewController.

7/ Again, check if `Session` exists.

8/ A `Session` is found! (By looking at `NSUserDefaults` for the one we stored to later reference). So I get `Session` I created earlier then give the user a choice to delete that one and start fresh or continue with that one.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] URLForKey:kKeyStoredSessionObjectIdUriRep];
    if (url) //Found existing flight session
    {
        NSManagedObjectID *objId = [self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:url];
        NSManagedObject *obj = [self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:objId];
        self.session = (Session *)obj;

        //Ask the user if they want to continue with this session or discard and start a new one
    }
```

9/ Choose to delete this `Session` and start a new one.

10/ **Problem begins here!** I delete the reference I am keeping to this `Session` as it is no longer relevant and try to delete the object then save those changes.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:kKeyStoredSessionObjectIdUriRep];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.session];
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
            {
                //Error!
            }
```

11/ There we have it, when I try to run the save method, it crashes and throws an error: `NSUnderlyingException = "Cannot delete object that was never inserted.";`

I have no clue why it says so, as I appear to save the object whenever I create one and create the reference, retrieve the object from that reference but then deleting just breaks everything.

Comment: I would try storing the objectID as opposed to the URI representation. Don't know if that solves your problem, but to me that seems a little more robust.

Comment: Check in debugger if managed object context is not nil when saving the session.

Comment: Where do you assert that your managedObjectContext is associated to the main thread? And where do you assert that your methods will be executed on the main thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your step 4. In this step you

1. Create the `Session`
2. Save its managed object ID to user defaults
3. Save changes to your managed object context.

The reason this fails is that when you create a new managed object, it has a temporary object ID that is only valid until you save changes. As soon as you save changes, it gets a new, permanent object ID. You're saving the temporary object ID, but when you look it up later it's not valid any more.

You can fix this just by changing the order of operations in step 4 so that you:

1. Create the `Session`
2. Save changes to your managed object context
3. Save the `Session`'s object ID to user defaults

This way you'll have a permanent ID when you save the value to user defaults.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks Tom.

Comment: This worked thank you, but the reference documentation says nothing about temporary objectID's not for NSEntityDescription nor for NSManagedObject. Also why does giving a temporary objectId return anything other than nil once there's no object for it anymore?

Comment: Temporary IDs are mentioned in the documentation for `NSManagedObjectID`, among other places. The `objectWithID` method is documented to **always** return an object.